# Run MySQL SELECT query for each value, returned by another SELECT

Tags: mysql, join

Even though this is basically a WordPress related problem, my question is strictly MySQL, so I am posting here as it probably will be more accurate.

I have two tables, `wp_posts` that contains basic data (e.g. IDs) of my products, and `wp_postmeta` that contains all additional data of those posts. I have this query:

```
SELECT count(p.ID) as in_stock_count 
FROM wp_postmeta as pm 
INNER JOIN wp_posts as p 
ON pm.post_id = p.ID 
WHERE p.post_type = 'product_variation' 
AND p.post_parent = 123456 
AND p.post_status = 'publish' 
AND pm.meta_key = '_stock_status' 
AND pm.meta_value = 'instock'
```

I can pass my product ID to this query (note the `123456` ID) and it returns the number of available variations of that product (`in_stock_count`). The query works very well for a single product ID.

This is a simple query that returns all product IDs from the wp_posts table:

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'publish'
```

**I need to somehow merge these two queries, so that the first query would run for each ID returned by the second query.** The returned table could have two columns: ID and in_stock_count

I'm kind of stuck here. Thank you for your help.

Comment: See JOIN and GROUP BY. If you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: How about `SELECT p.ID, count(p.ID) as in_stock_count ... ** the rest of your query ** .. GROUP BY p.ID`?

Comment: @fadlikidd That was the first thing I tried, it returns only one row (probably highest p.ID).

Comment: idk why @fadlikidd solution doesn't answer your question.

Comment: If like that, you need to provide some sample data into your question and illustrate your expected output. I'm guessing that in your current query, some of the condition in `WHERE` is making it to return only one row (probably `AND p.post_parent = 123456`). Another thing you could try is by adding the `SELECT p.ID .. ` and `GROUP BY p.ID` then remove all the `WHERE` condition. See how that would return.

Comment: Afterward you can re-add the `WHERE` condition one by one and re-run the query after adding each condition. That way you can see which of the `WHERE` is filtering the results. But if that doesn't help, you really [need to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65770786/edit) your question and add more details.

Comment: @fadlikidd You were right. Yes I forgot to remove `AND p.post_parent = XXX` from the WHERE clause. I actually did try that myself before posting here, but the query gave me wrong results (not the IDs I wanted). Turned out they were IDs of product variations, and not products. All I had to to was to add `SELECT p.post_parent, count(p.ID)` in the beginning, and then group with `GROUP BY p.post_parent` at the end. Thank you once again.

Comment: That happens to me quite a lot too. Glad I could help :)